# how to create simple model for Time Series Insight to separate sensors by devices

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I am ingesting TSI with the following sample data:

```
[{
    "deviceId": "testDevice1",
    "eventOriginTime": "2021-07-30T21:00:34.754Z",
    "x1": 24.270660400390625,
    "y1": 997.2078247070312,
    "z1": 25.398334503173828
},
{
    "deviceId": "testDevice2",
    "eventOriginTime": "2021-07-30T21:00:34.754Z",
    "x2": 24.270660400390625,
    "y2": 997.2078247070312,
    "z2": 25.398334503173828
}]
```

When the data shows up in TSI explorer - I can see two instances "testDevice1" and "TestDevice2", but when I click on any of them I can see "x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2" measurements.
More over if I select the serie x2 when looking for testDevice1 I get error this series does nor have any data.

I tried to understand the model based on official documentation but somehow I cannot relate this to my issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-model-overview#time-series-model-instances

Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you still blocked? Did you find a solution to your query?

Comment: yes, Just posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Microsoft Support I understood the concept behind the model. Basically every "Instance", in this case testDevice1, and testDevice2 are using DefaultType from Types, which does not distinguish which time series belong to which device.

All you need to do is to create new type for each device in "types" section of the model.
There you add "variables" - in this case you add x1,y1,z1 time series as variables to type testDevice1. And x2,y2,z2 time series as variables to type testDevice2.
Then under "Instances" you edit testDevice1 to be of type testDevice1 and testDevice2 to be of type testDevice2.

Once done - you have bound the right series with right devices.